# One value behind on HTTP service request using observables

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have the below Angular Service making an http request using debounce time. Im struggling to make it work as it is one value behind, can you tell me what im doing wrong? Also how can i improve it?

```
class Service {
    private searchSubject = new Subject<string>();
    private value;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.searchSubject
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap((searchTerm) => {
                    return this.http
                        .get('/search/locations')
                        .pipe(
                            map(response => response.content),
                        );
                }),
            )
            .subscribe((value) => {
                 console.log(value); // Correct value on first value change
                this.value = value;
            });
    }

    getLocations(searchTerm: string): Observable<LocationInformationSearchHit[]> {
        this.searchSubject.next(searchTerm);
        console.log(this.value); // Value is 'undefined' and with one value behind on each new searchTerm change

        return of(this.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better you use this code on the `component` level rather on the service, because when you leave the component, the service will not be destroyed in most cases and your subscription will be alive and cause a memory leak, also the below code

```
getLocations(searchTerm: string): Observable<LocationInformationSearchHit[]> {
        // below line informs the api call should run
        this.searchSubject.next(searchTerm);
        // will immediately subscribe to the old value instead of the latest api call value
       // which will be recieved later as a second emit
        return this.searchSubject.asObservable(); // Return the observable from BehaviorSubject
    }
```

Go for the code on the component level, we can just subscribe to the latest changes on the component level and it will always fetch the latest values!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {
  distinctUntilChanged,
  debounceTime,
  switchMap,
  map,
  delay,
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="search($event);">
<br/>
    Output: {{value}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  private searchSubject = new Subject<string>();
  name = 'Angular';
  value: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.searchSubject
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(500),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap((searchTerm) => {
            console.log('searchTerm', searchTerm);
            // simulate an API call
            return of({
              content: searchTerm,
            }).pipe(
              delay(1000),
              map((response: any) => response.content)
            );
          })
        )
        .subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value); // Correct value on first value change
          this.value = value;
        })
    );
  }

  search(searchStr: string) {
    this.searchSubject.next(searchStr);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.searchSubject.unsubscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ghrjgt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

if you want the best reusability, then mode the pipe operation to the service and subscribe to it on the component

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import {
  distinctUntilChanged,
  debounceTime,
  switchMap,
  delay,
  map,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  private searchSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  searchSubjectObservable$!: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.searchSubjectObservable$ = this.searchSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchTerm: any) => {
        // simulate an API call
        return of({
          content: searchTerm,
        }).pipe(
          delay(1000),
          map((response: any) => response.content)
        );
      })
    );
  }

  getLocations(searchStr: string) {
    this.searchSubject.next(searchStr);
  }
}
```

component

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="search($event);">
<br/>
    Output: {{value}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  name = 'Angular';
  value: any;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.testService.searchSubjectObservable$.subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value); // Correct value on first value change
        this.value = value;
      })
    );
  }

  search(searchStr: string) {
    this.testService.getLocations(searchStr);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
});
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fhxhuc?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)